# How Do I Import Classes From Another Package and Folder in Java?

Tags: java, oop, package

I just started studying OOP and Packages in Java. I have a question regarding package importing in Java.

I have two files, named `ImportThis.java` and `Here.java`

The directory for `ImportThis.java` on my local machine is `F:\VS Codes\master\folderone\folderoneone\ImportThis.java`. And the contents of `ImportThis.java` is:

```
package master.folderone.folderoneone;

public class ImportThis {
    public static void aStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The directory for `Here.java` on my local machine is `F:\VS Codes\master\foldertwo\foldertwotwo\Here.java`. And the contents of `Here.java` is:

```
package master.foldertwo.foldertwotwo;

public class Here {
    public static void anotherMethod() {
        ImportThis.aStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

By looking at the contents of `Here.java`, you might be able to tell that I want to import the class `ImportThis` from `ImportThis.java` to `Here.java`, and it is indeed what I've been trying to do. But both `ImportThis.java` and `Here.java` came from different folders and packages. I've tried using `import master.folderone.folderoneone.ImportThis;` on `Here.java` but VS Code says it cannot be resolved. Looking forward to the answer for my question!

EDIT: Changed package names and lowercased the folder names

Comment: java package names are case sensitive. Windows folder names are not case sensitive. Change folder names to lower case in windows.

Comment: I've lowercased all folder names and `import folderone.folderoneone.ImportThis;` still doesn't work

Comment: Show the error you are getting. Are you using IDE like eclipse or coding in text editor? Also let us know the command that you are using to compile the code.

Comment: I am editting my codes with VS Codes and the error from `Here.java` when i execute `anotherMethod()` in main is `ImportThis cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
package master.foldertwo.foldertwotwo;

import master.folderone.folderoneone.ImportThis; //<-import statement

public class Here {
    public static void anotherMethod() {
        ImportThis.aStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, the error says `ImportThis cannot be resolved`, however i noticed that java was able to resolve the import statement